# Cucumber, biggest challenge, browser invoke

Tags: cucumber

In my framework each feature file when converted to step def I have to put browser invoke codes (SetProperties) and for each operations new windows comes. Please help me resolve the issue I tried inherentance where i put the codes and extended to step def classes did not work. I want to open one browser and that will do the operations for every feature files.

For example: I have a feature file for login content verification and another feature file for after login.

I put in the login the userName and Password again I had to put userName and password cor the other feature file after login along with browser invoke codes.

Comment: Add ur relevant code

Comment: Please rewrite question to present clearer explanation and add some examples.

Comment: What language are you working in? What framework or library are you using? Can we have some code so that we can better answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

if you are still looking for answer. I would suggest initialize your browser in every step definition file or inside page object class(if you are using POM). create a class e.g: TestContext.java initialize your webdriver in that class.

public class TestContext {

```
private WebDriverLibrary webDriverLibrary;
private PageObjectLibrary pageObjectLibrary;

public TestContext() {
    webDriverLibrary = new WebDriverLibrary();
    pageObjectLibrary = new PageObjectLibrary(webDriverLibrary.getDriver());
}

// return WebDriverLibrary object
public WebDriverLibrary getWebDriverLibrary() {
    return webDriverLibrary;
}

// return PageObjectLibrary object
public PageObjectLibrary getPageObjectLibrary() {
    return pageObjectLibrary;
}
```

}

public class WebDriverLibrary {

```
private static WebDriver driver;
private static DriverType driverType;
private static EnvironmentType environmentType;

public WebDriverLibrary() {

    driverType = FileReaderLibrary.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowser();
    environmentType = FileReaderLibrary.getInstance().getConfigReader().getEnvironment();
}

// return webdriver instance
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    if (driver == null)
        driver = createDriver();
    return driver;
}

private WebDriver createDriver() {

    switch (environmentType) {
    case LOCAL:
        driver = createLocalDriver();
        break;
    case REMOTE:
        driver = createRemoteDriver();
        break;
    }
    return driver;

}
```

}

Hope this helps you.